# CakePHP retrieving HABTM data

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

Quick setup: `User` **hasAndBelongsToMany** `Course`

```
      courses_users
__________________________
id | user_id | course_id |
 1 |       1 |         1 |
 2 |       1 |         3 |
 3 |       2 |         5 |
```

I need to load all the `Courses` for the `User` with `users.id = 1`

**I tried this:**

```
$this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
$courses = $this->User->Courses->find('all');
```

But the code above retrieves all the courses instead of the associated to the user's ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your relations are in tact you need to do the following:

```
$this->User->read(null, $id);
or
$this->User->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>1)));
```

And it should return also the courses for the user. It depends from your app, but I would use Containable behaviour to retrieve only the courses, but really depends how many relations you have with user's model.

Having Containable behaviour you should load only Courses relation like that:

```
$this->User->find('first', 
   array(
      'conditions'=>array('id'=>1), 
      'contain'=>array('Courses')));
```

Comment: Used recursive = 1; and the first line was enough. But could you post an example of how can I get the Containable behavior please? the documentation isn't clear enough.

Comment: Containable behaviour is core behaviour included in the CakePHP. normally I just include it in the AppModel like: 
public $actsAs = array('Containable', ...); Then you can use it in find as easy as, specifying the relation table. It's good practice, since this way if you have a lot of relations, but you need only few of them, you can lightweight your queries with it. I think Containable behaviour doc, is clear enough: bit.ly/1gjCtRc

Answer (score 0):

```
 $course_ids = $this->CoursesUser->find('list', array('conditions'=>array('user_id'=>$this->Auth->user('id')), 'fields'=>'course_id'));

 $courses = $this->Course->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$course_ids)));
```

Comment: this won't work because courses doesn't have an user_id column. Since it is an HABTM relationship, the intermediate table has both foreign keys

Comment: what do you mean name field?

Comment: yeah, courses_users, and they have a HABTM relationship

Comment: yes, I have both foreing keys (course_id and user_id), and they are associated properly (since I can insert a row without a problem). The issue is that I don't know how to retrieve them.  I have updated the original post to describe better the issue

Comment: this retrieved the intermediate table (the one I drew in the question above), now I need the courses.